# Position from top on Tab-key

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a huge form on a website, when I press tab it automatically switches input fields (of course). And of course also the input jumps to the top if we hit the bottom.

However I have a fixed header on the top, which covers the first 60px. How can I jump the page 60px from the top instead of straight to the top?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` offset(), and dont forget to put a padding of 60px on top

**css**

```
body{ padding-top:60px}
```

give it a try

**JS**

```
$('input').offset().top + 60; //am adding you padding 60px here
```

to make it fancy you can use jquery animate

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('input').offset().top + 60
}, 2000);
```

to know more about `.offset` here is [official doc](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)